# Laravel 404 not found on resource

Tags: php, laravel

I created files using Way generator resource and then used below to map resources with URLs.

```
Route::resource('adpacks', 'AdpacksController');
```

However, it seems though http://laravel.dev/adpacks is returning 404 not found error.
But others such as http://laravel.dev/adpacks/create and http://laravel.dev/adpacks/1/edit seems to be working fine.

Is there a reason why index isn't working at all?

Also `GET /adpacks` - `adpacks.index` - `AdPacksController@index` is showing on registered routes list in CLI

Comment: What does `php artisan routes` say?

Comment: I just updated my question. It shows GET /adpacks but still generates 404 error some how?

Comment: You might want to post your code here so it'll be easier to identify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but for anyone encountering the same problem: I found the solution:

Turns out my route was interfering with some other routes. I moved the line further up the web.php file, and it worked. Renaming the route also bypasses the problem.

Comment: Please try to formulate your answer matching the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like other route override that route.

Please take the line at the top of the route file.

```
Route::resource('adpacks', 'AdpacksController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just here to confirm, because it happened with me for almost 3-4 days. And no laravel community helped in this.

So anyone seeing this, hope to get help from this experience.

--For me, no replacing the lines worked though it could be helpful for some reason and people should try it.
But I just renamed the route and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to check the parameters in your controller

Example:

If you have the type of code below, a 404 error will happen:

```
public function edit(Object $object)
    {
}
```

So you can go to your controller and change it:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
}
```

You can try to explore if your code enter in the Route echoing a "hello" for example:

```
Route::post('/audio', function () {
        dd("hello);
    });
```

This helped me thus maybe can help you.