# Laravel 8 resource controller 404 not found

Tags: laravel-8

2022-10-26 
previous debug has found port setting error.

---

Previous/same questions
But none of them worked
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64332325/404-not-found-in-laravel-8\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64332325/404-not-found-in-laravel-8%5C)
[Laravel 404 not found on resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008565/laravel-404-not-found-on-resource)

Trying to learn how to use Laravel Resource Controllers
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

I've encountering two different funny problem that:

- Even the index exists still return 404 pages;
- When I move `index.blade.php` to `/app/views/` but the subside `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars` shows correctly;
- When I use `route:clear` and `route:cache` both side `http://127.0.0.1:8000` nor `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars` work and became 404 pages;

The codes:
web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CarsController;

Route::resource('/cars', CarsController::class);
```

index.blade.php

```
<H2>#resource-controllers</H2>
```

CarsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CarsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }
```

and the last I've check the route:list

```
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                 | Name                        | Action                                                     | Middleware                               |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user            | generated::xxxxxxxx| Closure                                                    | api                                      |
|        |           |                     |                             |                                                            | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum |
|        | GET|HEAD  | cars                | cars.index                  | App\Http\Controllers\CarsController@index                  | web                                      |
|        | POST      | cars                | cars.store                  | App\Http\Controllers\CarsController@store                  | web                                      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | cars/create         | cars.create                 | App\Http\Controllers\CarsController@create                 | web                                      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | cars/{car}          | cars.show                   | App\Http\Controllers\CarsController@show                   | web                                      |
|        | PUT|PATCH | cars/{car}          | cars.update                 | App\Http\Controllers\CarsController@update                 | web                                      |
|        | DELETE    | cars/{car}          | cars.destroy                | App\Http\Controllers\CarsController@destroy                | web                                      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | cars/{car}/edit     | cars.edit                   | App\Http\Controllers\CarsController@edit                   | web                                      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | sanctum/csrf-cookie | generated::xxxxxxxx| Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Controllers\CsrfCookieController@show | web                                      |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

I'm still trying to find any kinds solution of this,
but so far couldn't figure out which part went wrong.

[wrong place index.blade.php but shows pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeOad.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a minor mistake

about the address port setting

I've change the log-in account while debug-ing

after few days change the

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars`
to
`http://127.0.0.1:8001/cars`

the `blade.index.php` shows the specific page correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try: `Route::get("/cars",[CarsController::class,'index']);`

Comment: no luck, thanks;
I'm trying edit path to docs maybe find out something